# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadEnvVariables on channel flutter_config)

Tags: flutter

When ever I am trying to run the app using chrome its giving me exception MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadEnvVariables on channel flutter_config) and only blank white screen is shown every time.

Answer (score 1):

[flutter_config](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config) doesn't support web platform - only Android and iOS.

> Plugin that exposes environment variables to your Dart code in Flutter as well as to your native code in iOS and Android.